# Manifest[T].erasure is deprecated in 2.10, what should I use now?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, scala-2.10, erasure

I have the following code:

```
object Log {

  def get[T](implicit manifest : Manifest[T] ) = {
    LoggerFactory.getLogger( manifest.erasure.getName )
  }

  def getByName( name : String ) = {
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(name)
  }

}
```

The idea is to use it like this:

```
object SimpleFuture {
  val log = Log.get[SimpleFuture[Throwable,Nothing]]
}
```

But the compiler (2.10) now says that `manifest.erasure` is deprecated. What should I use now for this same functionality?

Comment: Not familiar with using these tools myself, but I believe what you want to look into are `TypeTag`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest fix is to replace the call to `erasure` with a call to `runtimeClass`.  If you run with `-deprecation`, the compiler actually gives that recommendation:

```
warning: method erasure in trait ClassManifestDeprecatedApis is deprecated: Use runtimeClass instead
```

Alternatively, you can use a class tag:

```
def get[T](implicit tag : reflect.ClassTag[T] ) = {
  LoggerFactory.getLogger( tag.runtimeClass.getName )
}
```

This alternative is more future proof than using `Manifest`.  `Manifest` is due for deprecation in 2.10.something or soon after.  See the "Type Tags and Manifests" section of [this document](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you're only interested in avoiding deprecation warnings then you can also use **manifest.runtimeClass.getName** (instead of manifest.erasure.getName).

IE:

```
def classOp[T](implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) {
  println("Class: " + manifest.runtimeClass.getName)
}
```

I've also found another technique which I don't fully understand and may or may not be useful...

```
def classOp[T <: Any : Manifest] {
  println("Class: " + manifest[T].runtimeClass.getName)
}
```